# Medal Of Honor Warfighter (PC) error-" DirectX function "GetDeviceRemovedReason" failed with DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_HUNG "

Tags: pc, graphics-card, medal-of-honor, directx-11

After upgrading to Windows 10 I get the above mentioned error every time I die in an online match, and then the game crashes. It also happens when I try to see my platoon card in the game.

I tried every fix I could find:

- Disabling Origin in game
- Executing Directx setup
- Disabling v-sync
- Lowering the graphics to minimum
- Playing in windowed mode
- Lowering the GPU clock cycle

Nothing helped.

I reverted to an older driver 14.9 and it helped, but it made the booting time of Windows very long and it operated slow. Right now I use the 15.7.1 driver. I also tried the beta driver and the game didn't even start.

Some info about my pc:

- Windows 10 64bit
- Sapphire AMD r7 260x OC

If someone has a magical solution to this I will be glad to read it.

Comment: The error means that the GPU/VPU crashed and has been recovered by the OS. While this is most likely a driver issue plain and simple, MS asserts that DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_HUNG means that an improper command was sent and that it is a programming problem. So, do a game file integrity check or reinstall. There may be corrupt artwork related to the badges etc.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the latest DX from Microsoft's site: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35

Try to get the **BETA** driver for your card. (The stable one might not be updated to Win10 yet)

Check if this tread might have some stuff that can help you: https://battlelog.medalofhonor.com/mohw/forum/threadview/2832654490099421775/1/

You can try to remove your old config data:

> Remove the saved profiles for the game from your computer to allow
>   for a reset to the default. Go to your My Documents folder on your
>   computer . Delete the mohw folder. Restart the game to get new
>   profiles. ~ (From the Battlelog Forum - BosieRascal)

You can try to force the game to run using DX10 instead.

Comment: Over the years I have found that many directx crashes go away when running the game with a lower version of directx.

Comment: @CamelCase Same here. Depends on you GPU o\c but the drivers' older DX compatibility is normally much more stable. ;)